# Tweepy UnicodeEncodeError in streaming filter code

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the following code, with which I want to collect Tweets geolocated to the UK, written in english and with the keywords regarding the topics "death" and "covid". I am still very new to all of this, so bear with me, the code is definetly not ideal. After some hours of streaming, I always get the message "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f449' [...] character maps to " tracebacked to the stream.filter line (last line). First I thought it was because of all the strings, so I added the "u" before every string, but it didn't help.

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        if (u'death' in status.text.lower() or u'dead' in status.text.lower() or u'decease' in status.text.lower()) and (u'corona' in status.text.lower() or u'covid' in status.text.lower()):
            print(status)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    mystreamlistener = StdOutListener()
    #This handles Twitter authentification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API

    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, mystreamlistener)

    # stream filtered by location in United Kingdom
    stream.filter(locations=[-6.38,49.87,1.77,55.81], languages=[u'en'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a workound:
As only very few tweets seem to cause this error, I just wrapped the whole if-statement in the method on_status with a try/except.